# can we plot dendrogram on frontend by using django backend

Tags: javascript, django, visualization, dendrogram

I am working on a clustering based project where I have to perform dendrogram operation on backend and to plot that chart on front-end using any javascript based framework (angular). So I know how to do it in python but on front-end how can I plot that because the data from python SciPy library is like nested lists which use line plots while in front-end libraries they accept data as parent child relation.

In case I am not clear then do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of effort I have found the plotly.js which is just like a python plotly but it's a javascript version and can be used for plotting. It takes the input argument from the scipy dendrogram function. these arguments are:

```
dendrogram['icoord']
dendrogram['dcoord']
```

you can visit this link for more information:

https://codepen.io/NTX11/pen/qrdyjX

this work in my case. as I need to plot dendrogram on frontend